# Weka's StringToWordVector filter from command line?

Tags: terminal, weka

Is it possible to run the [StringToWordVector](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) filter in Weka from the command line and get a processed output file? I'd like to pre-process my data separately before feeding it back into Weka for training. So I'm trying to run the filter, get an output file, and then do the rest. I am using a high-end GPU virtual machine with SSH-only access, so I can't use the Weka GUI, only the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.in/2013/05/language-identification-as-text.html)

```
java weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector -O -L -tokenizer "weka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \" \\r\\n\\t.,;:\\\"\\'()?!-¿¡+*&#$%\\\\/=<>[]_`@\"" -W 10000000 -b -i input-train.arff -o output-train-vector.arff -r input-test.arff -s output-test-vector.arff
```

Comment: Thanks, this almost worked, but I'm getting the following error on Ubuntu: "-bash: !-¿¡+*: event not found"

Comment: looks like char encoding issue. just include relevant delimeters and ignore the rest. see if it works.